# Is it possible to create BehaviourSubject<void>() without initial value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm using a `BehaviourSubject` purely as trigger, so the payload doesn't matter. The subject should "fire" (call `next`) on subscription (a simple **`Subject` wouldn't work**!). In principle it would be enough to have a `BehaviourSubject<void>` for this purpose:

```
const readonly trigger = new BehaviourSubject<void>()
                                                   ^^
                                                   must not be empty
```

However, it seems to be impossible to create such a subject. Or is there a way to create a `BehaviourSubject` of type `void` without an initial value?

Comment: Sure, the payload doesn't matter but there has to **be** a payload. How else can you tell the difference between a stream that doesn't emit and a stream that emits nothing? Those two things looks the same. Consider any other signal. "When I say **'BERRY'**, you start the race" - sure it doesn't matter what word you use, but it wouldn't therefore make sense to say "When I don't say anything, then you start the race." That would be a very poor signal indeed. - I would just pick a boolean or null (small memory footprint) and go with it.

Comment: @MrkSef No, there doesn't have to be a payload. The observer will be notified that _something_ happened even if there is no value, since the `next` method of the observer will be called. See [StackBlitz exmple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rx-playground-34jqyz?file=index.ts)

Comment: `undefined` is a payload though. In javascript, an uninitialized value actually has the value `undefined`. `undefined` is a primitive type. As strange as it sounds, you are initializing your BehaviorSubject with `undefined`. Your lamba that you pass a parameter to the subscription is called with `undefined`.

Comment: That is true. But important to me is to avoid calling `next` with a useless value that could even be misunderstood (because someone sees a meaning in the value itself). And then there is no payload on `next`.

Comment: It seems to me that null is semantically pretty clear in this case. Typescript will complain as well if you try ` trigger.next()`. It should say something like `next` expects 1 parameter and you've entered 0. So you'd be doing something like trigger.next(null) there as well. In Javascript, `trigger.next()` is the same as `trigger.next(undefined)` so if you want to keep the typescript compiler happy while making it feel closest to a vanilla JS function call without parameters, then `undefined` may be the ticket.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

clearly `Subject` doesn't meet your needs as you want a trigger on subscription. you can set the initial value to `undefined` though...

```
new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined)
```

or `null` should work fine too.

Comment: Thanks, `undefined` works. `null` does not, at least not in TypeScript strict mode.